# Selecting all between 2 separate date ranges ie 2019-2018 and 2107-2016

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select all records between 2 separate date ranges.

For example all records between 2019-12-31 to 2019-01-01 and also 2017-12-31 to 2017-01-01

I want to also if required be able to add another date range to the query but they may not follow ie they may miss a year.

I just can't get my head around the mysql code for this process.

At the moment i'm using this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM sa_incidents 
WHERE
incidentDate 
BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' 
OR '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

I expect the result to show all records in-between those dates.

However, it shows all records within the whole table with any date even 2014.

If i use the AND operator it shows only the first range ie all dates for 2019.

Comment: `2017-12-31 to 2017-01-01` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this after wrapping both **BETWEEN** in seperate parenthesis `()`

```
SELECT * FROM sa_incidents 
WHERE
(incidentDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31')
OR (incidentDate  BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31')
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. So close yet so far away :-) simple when you know how.

Comment: Glad it helps you somehow